# Tattoo removal video effect

Tags: after-effects, video-editor, editing, effects, visual-effects

Is there a video editor that has a video effect where tattoos on human skin can be motion tracked and filtered out frame by frame, either by blurring them, or replacing the tattoos with surrounding skin pigment?

Comment: You can do it in Premiere Pro. Google for "premiere pro mask tracking", you'll find loads of videos and tutorials. Usually people do it to blur faces, but in the same way it can be done with a tattoo

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that it's not changing perspective or moving around too much, I would use a tracker on the tattoo and a clone stamp from another area of skin.  More elaborate removal could be done with [Mocha](https://borisfx.com/products/mocha-ae-cc-mocha-for-after-effects/), or using a mesh warping tracker like [Lockdown](https://aescripts.com/lockdown/), which has a demo of tattoo removal in their showreel at 0m24s:

Comment: Could you edit with a link to mocha

Comment: good idea - added

Comment: Might want to also mention AE's new content aware fill.

Comment: Could you go in more detail about what clone stamp is and settings for tracking skin pigment to mask the black tattoo with